# TSV import issue

Tags: import

I am having an issue importing a tab-seperated file properly. Most lines get split into elements based on the tabs but some don't:

```
test = Import["test.txt", "TSV", "Numeric" -> False];
test[[1 ;; 1]][[All, {1}]]
```

would return

```
{{SGD}}
```

but `test[[2 ;; 2]][[All, {1}]]` returns

```
{{SGD   S000004984  BDP1        GO:0000126  SGD_REF:S000045738|PMID:7568218 IDA     C   Essential subunit of RNA polymerase III transcription factor (TFIIIB)   YNL039W|B"|TFC5|TFC7|TFIIIB90|transcription factor TFIIIB subunit BDP1}}
```

the sample test.txt file would contain the following two lines (I replaced all tabs with "\t", otherwise they appear as spaces on the post):

```
SGD\tS000000057\tBDH2\t\tGO:0052587\tSGD_REF:S000124037\tIEA\tEC:1.1.1.303\tF\tPutative medium-chain alcohol dehydrogenase with similarity to BDH1\tYAL061W|putative dehydrogenase BDH2\tgene\ttaxon:559292\t20150103\tUniProt\t\t
SGD\tS000004984\tBDP1\t\tGO:0000126\tSGD_REF:S000045738|PMID:7568218\tIDA\t\tC\tEssential subunit of RNA polymerase III transcription factor (TFIIIB)\tYNL039W|B"|TFC5|TFC7|TFIIIB90|transcription factor TFIIIB subunit BDP1\tgene\ttaxon:559292\t20090831\tSGD\t\t
```

I would appreciate some help - on whether I am doing smt wrong or a way to get this right.

Thanks!

Comment: I reproduced that behavior on my MMA as well. Interestingly, you can convert your TSV to a CSV, and then the Import works flawlessly, but you are correct, the TSV fails on the second line.

Comment: Thanks for checking @MarcoB . Converting to CSV didn't change the result for me actually. I'll update to 10.1 and try again.

Comment: @MarcoB yes, the update does fix it. Thanks again.

Comment: meono, would you have time to report this to WRI as a possible bug/issue in the importing of TSV?

Comment: @meono are you sure that 10.1 resolves the issue? Output I posted below is from `$Version="10.1.0  for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)"`

Comment: @MarcoB , I sent a report with a link to this post.

Comment: @xcah ,you are right. I must have read the wrong lines on my original file. The issue is present for both CSV and TSV import.

Comment: Thank you! I'd appreciate it if you could keep us posted here as well.

Comment: Just an update, the problem is recognised and hopefully will be fixed eventually:
"It does appear that the Import function is not behaving properly in this case and I have forwarded an incident report to our developers with the information you provided."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a stray quote on the second line, in

```
YNL039W|B"|TFC5|TFC7|TFIIIB90
```

the effect of which can be seen here (test.txt is your input)

```
In[1]:= test=Import["~/Desktop/test.txt","TSV","Numeric"->False];
In[2]:= Length/@test
Out[2]= {17,7}
In[3]:= test//Last//TableForm
Out[3]//TableForm= SGD  S000004984  BDP1        GO:0000126  SGD_REF:S000045738|PMID:7568218 IDA     C   Essential subunit of RNA polymerase III transcription factor (TFIIIB)   YNL039W|B"|TFC5|TFC7|TFIIIB90|transcription factor TFIIIB subunit BDP1
gene
taxon:559292
20090831
SGD
```

Comment: Thanks @xcah , I noticed the quote as well but I'd prefer to keep it. Unless there is a way to deal with it, I'd convert to CSV in stead.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm afraid that the quote is not stray, i.e. it may be correct in that context. You are correct in saying that the quote messes up the TSV import though, but funnily enough not the CSV import, so I would tend to think that it should be properly handled in the TSV import routine, but it is not. (+1)

Comment: According to http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180, the "correct" way to escape a double-quote is to quote the field with double-quotes, and then double the literal double-quote. When I do this, Mathematica processes the field breaks correctly, but the field containing the literal double-quote contains a double-quote instead of a single quote.  I'd say that's a bug.

Comment: Thanks for checking @xcah . I'll report it.